# How to sync scene object's rigidbody (kinematic) over the network?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am using photon pun2 for networking. it's a simple pick and throw scene where players on network trying to pick and throw the ball.
My scene contains a ball that players can pick and throw. When picking the object I am making ball's kinematic true and for throw kinematic is false using punrpc and ipunobersvable

syncing rigidbody kinematic across the network is an issue. this way rigidbody kinematic is switching between off and on.

I am using photonrigidbodyview for syncing over the network. velocity and angular velocity with transform is perfectly synced.

Here is the code

```
    private void Start()
    {          
           
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            ball = GameObject.Find("IceBall").transform;
            rb = GameObject.Find("IceBall").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            coll = GameObject.Find("IceBall").GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
 
        
            //ballContainer = player.Find("ObjectGuide").transform;
            //fpsCamera = player.Find("CameraHolder").transform;
        
       
        //setup 
        if (!equipped)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            coll.isTrigger = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            coll.isTrigger = true;
            slotFull = true;
        }
 
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 distanceToPlayer = ball.position - transform.position;
        if(!equipped && distanceToPlayer.magnitude<=pickupRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)&&!slotFull)
        {
            photonView.RPC("PickUp", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, true);
        }
        if(equipped && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            photonView.RPC("Drop", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, false);
            
        }
    }
 
    [PunRPC]
    public void PickUp(bool _kinematic)
    {
        if(equipped == false && slotFull == false)
        {
            equipped = true;
            slotFull = true;
            Debug.Log("ball is equipped "+equipped);
            ball.GetComponent<PhotonView>().TransferOwnership(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
            rb.isKinematic = _kinematic;
 
            coll.isTrigger = true;
 
            //Make ball a child of the camera and move it to default position 
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {   
                ball.parent = ballContainer;
                ball.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                ball.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
            }
      
        }
 
 
    }
 
    [PunRPC]
    public void Drop(bool _kinematic)
    {
        if(equipped == true && slotFull == true)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<PhotonView>().TransferOwnership(null);
            animator.SetTrigger("IsThrowBall");
            equipped = false;
            slotFull = false;
 
            //set parent to null 
            ball.SetParent(null);
 
 
            //Make Rigidbody is not Kinematic and BoxCollider normal
            rb.isKinematic = _kinematic;
            coll.isTrigger = false;
 
            //Ball carries momentum of player 
           
            //addforce 
            rb.AddForce(fpsCamera.forward * dropForwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            rb.AddForce(fpsCamera.up * dropUpwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
       
 
    }
 
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
 
 
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            // We own this player: send the others our data
            stream.SendNext(rb.isKinematic);
            stream.SendNext(coll.isTrigger);
        }
        else
        {
            // Network player, receive data
            this.rb.isKinematic = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
            this.coll.isTrigger = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You said "I am using photonrigidbodyview for syncing over the network. velocity and angular velocity with transform is perfectly synced." So what is the problem ?

Comment: syncing rigidbody's kinematic property across the network is an issue.

Comment: Then i would suggest looking into SyncVar, or you need to use Commands and Rpc calls to sync them.